# Three.js camera does not follow parent's lookAt

Tags: three.js, camera, parent

When a camera is attached to an object, it won't follow object's lookAt.
Shouldn't a child be aligned to the parent and follow its moves, or what?

Comment: [This conversation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/737) might help clarify the apparent discrepancy.

Comment: Yes, when a camera is attached to an object, it is aligned backwards in reference to object's lookAt. When I rotated the child camera 180 degrees on Y axis, it was aligned and followed properly, which is obviously a workaround to this fundamental bug. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to bring it up again on github. It has been several years, so it might be a good time to restart the conversation.